# Help understanding the proof in the book Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class

Tags: inequality

[image]
[image]

**Background:** This is one of the problems in the book Cauchy Schwarz Master Class by Steele.

**My questions:** I don't understand how can one get the bound \begin{align*}
F^2(x) &\geq \int_0^h u^2|f(u)|^2 \, du = \int_0^h (x+t)^2|f(x+t)|^2 \, dt \\
&\geq \int_0^h (x+t)^2|f(x)-t^{1/2}D(x)|^2 \, dt \\
&\geq hx^2(f(x)-h^{1/2}D(x))^2
\end{align*}
I know that the second line comes from the lower bound 7.13, but I don't understand how does one get the first line and the third line in here. Also, where does the bound for $h$ come from? Can anyone help me understanding it? Thank you!